# How to pass table name into the query to show data of table in report viewer?

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, reportviewer, dataadapter

How can we pass name of a table as a parameter to report viewer or table adapter to show the data of given table in report viewer.

Comment: what you have done so far to achieve it ?

Comment: better share how you are trying to achieve it to get quick solution.

Comment: WHen we create a dataset for report viewer at that time in the query we add the parameter of table name which we want to show in report viewer.

Comment: Or There any other way to show the data of a specific table which user newly created dynamically as report to print.

Comment: not quite sure what you want. please add some example what you are trying to do.

Comment: I just want to show the data of table which user enter data and create table on run time in data base and system show the dynamically created table data in report viewer.